# A view query that takes too long - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have view that queries from 2 tables:
A messages table and a message status table.
each message has several statuses.

The purpose of the view is to calculate for every message its first and last statuses:

```
with last_msg_status as (
  select distinct on (message_id) message_id,date,type
  from message_status
  order by message_id,date desc
), first_msg_status as (
  select distinct on (message_id) message_id,date,type
  from message_status
  order by message_id,date
)
select *
from messages m
  join last_msg_status ls on ls.message_id = m.id
  join first_msg_status fs on fs.message_id = m.id;
```

I have an index on the (message_id,date) in the statuses table.
The query takes me 8 seconds - and I would like to improve it.

Do you have any ideas? I was thinking of using materialized view - but I got into trouble using it (doing refresh took me forever) - any best practices I should know of? Does it even recommended?

Thanks a lot,
comet.

**edit:**
for example,

messages contains:

```
id    data
0     'aa'
1     'bb'
```

message_status contains:

```
id    message_id      date       type
1000     0          11/11/18     'new'
1001     0          15/11/18     'sent'
1003     0          2/12/18      'done'
1004     1          11/11/18     'new'
1005     1          15/11/18     'sent'
```

the result should be:

```
id    data    creation_date      first_type    cur_status_date   cur_status_type
0     'aa'    11/11/18            'new'           2/12/18          'done'
1     'bb'    11/11/18            'new'           15/11/18         'sent'
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: Your query really only mentions one table -- there is no `message_status`.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I added an example - hope my problem will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first and last status for each message, I would suggest starting with the right tables and seeing if a correlated subquery works:

```
select m.*,
       (select ms.status
        from mesasge_status ms
        where ms.message_id = m.id
        order by ms.date asc
        limit 1
       ) as first_status,
       (select ms.status
        from mesasge_status ms
        where ms.message_id = m.id
        order by ms.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as last_status
from messages m;
```

This should at least come closer to accomplishing what you seem to want.  If `message_status` has an index on `(message_id, date)`, then this might meet your performance goals.

EDIT:

If you want more than one column you can use tuples -- or more realistically, lateral joins:

```
select m.*, ms_first.*, ms_last.*
from messages m cross join lateral
     (select . . .
      from mesasge_status ms
      where ms.message_id = m.id
      order by ms.date asc
      limit 1
     ) ms_first cross join lateral
      (select . . .
      from mesasge_status ms
      where ms.message_id = m.id
      order by ms.date desc
      limit 1
     ) ms_last;
```

Comment: The only problem with this method is that I can only select one column per subquery...so lets say I want to select ms.status and ms.date - it will extend drastically the execution time...

Comment: It sounds good but unfortunately it doesn't improve the performance :/
I don't know what else to do...

Comment: @CometKapaNu . . . Do you have the recommended index?

Comment: yes, and yet I can't get it done in less than 8 seconds

Comment: @CometKapaNu . . . Presumably, your `messages` table is pretty large, so the query is generating a large volume of data.

Comment: message table contains 80k rows, and statuses table contains 250k rows.
is it considered large volume of data?

Comment: @CometKapaNu . . . Well, it could be if you are selecting all the columns from `message` and the rows are big.